# Appium with WebdriverIO v8: @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I am setting up an automated test using **appium with webdriverIO version 8,** mocha framework. Please watch [this video for a clearer picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7poolyya3wkuml/ESM%20module%20Error.mov?dl=0)

My capabilities are:

const path = require ('path');

```
capabilities: [{
    
        'appium:platformName': 'Android',
        'appium:platformVersion': '12.0',
        'appium:deviceName:': 'Pixel 6 Android ver.12',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'appium:app':path.join (process.cwd(), 'webdriverio-appium-v8/app/android/ApiDemos-debug.apk')
        
    }],
```

I activated the android emulator and ran `npx wdio` command and got the following:

```
2023-01-05T10:40:45.674Z ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///Users/xxx/Documents/webdriverio-appium-v8/wdio.conf.js: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/xxx/Documents/webdriverio-appium-v8/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/xxx/Documents/webdriverio-appium-v8/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///Users/xxx/Documents/webdriverio-appium-v8/wdio.conf.js:1:14
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue:  This is what I did

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete "type": "module" from package.json file
   change export const config to exports.config
2. specs: [
   // ToDo: define location for spec files here
   path.join(process.cwd(),'./test/specs/**/*.js')],
3. capabilities: [{
   'appium:platformName': 'Android',
   'appium:platformVersion': '12.0',
   'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_6',
   'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
   'appium:app':path.join (process.cwd(), 'app/android/v0.5.1-rc1.apk'),

   }],

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).